# Physics issue - spheres are floating above the floor

Tags: physics

Is there any physics expert who can have a look to my file please?
I created a scene with a slide were at the end some spheres / balls jump out.
But the balls don't touch the ground ...
The collision shape of the ground is set to Mesh / Final so what could be the problem? That's for your help in advance!

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/09d218ce2728918e10d9b7871044bdc520200228192244/41885b9cab282bc663d24428a650844a20200228192244/3b8281

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the floor Rigid Body / Sensitivity, lower Margin.

For optimization purposes, it would be a good idea to replace the floor mesh by an invisible plane, with a collision shape set to Box. (And set the shape of the balls to Sphere instead of Mesh)

Comment: Changing the collision shape of the balls to Sphere did solve the issue. Thanks for your help!